# Manually mock is not imported in Nestjs

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I created a `__mocks__/post.service.ts` to mock `post.service`.

```js
export const findAllFn = jest.fn();
export const PostService = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    findAll: findAllFn,
  };
});
```

And import the items in my test.

```js
import { PostController } from './post.controller';

jest.mock('./post.service');

import { PostService, findAllFn } from './post.service';
import { TestingModule, Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

describe('Post Controller(jest mock manually loading from mocks files)', () => {
  let controller: PostController;
  let postService: PostService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [PostService],
      controllers: [PostController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<PostController>(PostController);
    postService = module.get<PostService>(PostService);
  });

  it('should get all posts', async () => {
    await controller.getAllPosts();
    expect(findAllFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

When ran the test and got the errors.

```sh
Module '"./post.service"' has no exported member 'findAllFn'
import { PostService, findAllFn } from './post.service';
```

But according to [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock), it should be imported.

Comment: It's TS error. It happens on compilation and cannot be affected by whatever happens in `__mocks__/post.service.ts`. It refers to original module. It means that original module doesn't have findAllFn.

Comment: @EstusFlask I added jest links. Have a look at the manual mocks section, it adds another `export const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();` in the mock file and can be imported in tests.

Comment: Again, this is purely TS error that happens on compilation. It doesn't mean that an export isn't really there, it means that TS didn't find it. Jest docs refer to JS, so they are irrelevant here. Please, post original module.

Comment: Btw, from your another question it's clear that it's findAll and not findAllFn. Thanks to TS for catching mistakes on sight.